# How does the parameter "offset" work with the ST_LocateAlong/ST_LocateBetween PostGIS function?

Tags: postgis, linear-referencing

I try to understand the `ST_LocateAlong/ST_LocateBetween` PostGIS function. The documentation tells me this:

> geometry ST_LocateAlong(geometry ageom_with_measure, float8 a_measure,
>   float8 offset);
>
> Return a derived geometry collection value with
>   elements that match the specified measure. Polygonal elements are not
>   supported.
>
> If an offset is provided, the resultant will be offset to the left or
>   right of the input line by the specified number of units. A positive
>   offset will be to the left, and a negative one to the right.

I understand that a point will be returned if feed in a LineM and a measure.
But what is the use of an offset? Will the output point be shifted?

Similar to the offset in `ST_LocateBetween` - Will the output line substring be shifted? The documentation of `ST_LocateBetween` does not touch the parameter offset.

I know that I would just have to try it but I am still missing these skills, nevertheless I do need the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the skills faster than expected:

**offset parameter with ST_LocateAlong()** - 
Positive offset will move the point left of the line - negative offset will move the point right of the line in map units.

**offset parameter with ST_LocateBetween()** - 
Positive offset will move the line left of the line - negative offset will move the line right of the line in map units. This shift of the lines is not a simple shift it works more like a buffer. The end parts have a strange behaviour see picture below. The black line is the original, the red line is the result of ST_LocateBetween() with a given offset.

[image]